# asignar una variable global Twig

Tags: php, template, twig

hola estoy aprendiendo a usar twig, y no puedo asignar una variable para usar en todos los templates, en la documentacion dice

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('text', new Text());
```

y yo lo uso asi

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('tsConfig', $tsCore->settings);
```

y no me da nada en el template, como tendria que hacerlo?

Comment: Y que hay dentro de settings? En tus templates imprimes esa variable o iteras sobre ella?

Answer (score 0):

Primero en la sintaxis no veo problema guiandome de la documentacion asi que la pregunta seria como estas usando dicha variable??

Mira aqui la informacion de twig en español.

http://gitnacho.github.io/Twig/advanced.html#globales